# Is it possible to insert shortcode inside Header menu or top-bar menu in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have made a simple shortcode for my wordpress theme. I'm trying to align it on right-side above the corner of my page. Is it possible to insert shortcode function.php?

I want to place my Short-code in the [top-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUwI.png) (right side above the corner) so that it will work for each pages. Means if i click on any menu then the shortcode should have to work on that menu also.

Actually i'm new in web development. Please suggest me what shall i have to do so it will align where i want and should have work for each module.

Comment: before to ask how to use shortcode, have you ever found how to put a custom text at this place ? once you have found this, just use the code `echo do_shortcode($content);` to execute shortcode in the content.

Comment: yes i know.. I used it in my page . and it's working. But i don't want to put inside each page.. I just want to align it inside the header menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wordpress function for that. Please open the file on which you have to place shortcode. Like if you want to place it on header open header.php and add

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]'); ?>
```

where you want your shortcode content to appear

Comment: It's working... But i'm just aligning it in the right side above the corner.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to find the top bar menu hook of your theme and then add this code (adapted for your needs) in your function.php child theme :

```
function my_shotcode_inside_top_bar ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_page() && $args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
        $items .= '<li class="my-class">' . do_shortcode( "[my_shortcode]" ) . '</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_shotcode_inside_top_bar', 10, 2 );
```

**is_page** displays the shortcode in pages only but you can choose [another condition](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) or no condition at all.

**secondary** is the hook and it depends on your theme. You can normally find it in your theme header.php file.

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

A menu location selector should be added - that way some themes support multiple menus, and some are called "top" or custom added.

The shortcode could then contain a call to whatever a menu position is:

EG: `[myshortcode menu="secondary"]`

*Didn't have enough points to add this as a comment.*